# Android: How to make app run on all Android mobiles

Tags: android, service, jsoup

I am developing an app dedicated for services offered by a website. Using this app, user is able to login to actual website and perform activities.

In coding part, I am using JSOUP 1.6.1 jar for my Android app. This jar allows me to connect to internet. This app is working great on Sony Xperia, all Android Emulator and even Galaxy emulator. But, when my app is run on other mobile phones, the connection with that website is not established and hence, my app is failing.

I am using Android 2.3+, API Level 10 for my app.

I have granted all the permissions to Android app related to accessing internet.

Does JSOUP run on all Android mobiles??? If it is running, can you please tell me why my app is not working on other Android mobiles.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you are developing with API level 10, then your app won't run on any device with a lower API level. You can set your project's API level to something lower to see if you are using any API calls that are incompatible with earlier levels. If so, then perhaps you can replace them with other API calls. Otherwise, you may be stuck with running only on API level 10+ devices.

Also, see [this blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/how-to-have-your-cupcake-and-eat-it-too.html) for how to develop backward-compatible apps.

Comment: I have developed on API level 8 and Android version 2.2 also.but It is not allowing to establish internet connections with JAR Jsoup1.6.1's Connection and other methods.My code is running on Sony Xperia phone(Android verion 2.3.4) but it is not running on other phones such as HTC or Samsung with android version 2.3.4 and 2.3.4+.So i guess problem is with that JAR only?I have to submit my project next monday so if u can help me it will be great.

Comment: When i run my app on Sony Xperia or emulator it will make connections and it will generate cookies too but when i run it on other android phone it is generating less cookies means no connections will be established.so could not execute App So i guess problem is with JAR only?

Comment: @Alex - Does the manifest file declare `<uses-permission name="android.permission.INTERNET">`?